# how to know is bluetooth exists in win8 device?

Tags: c#, windows-8, bluetooth

I found a way that use try catch with `PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync()`

But I don't know is bluetooth hardware doesn't exist or bluetooth closed.

How to know difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Codeexamples), you can determine bluetooth is off by checking the `HResult` of an exception caught when calling `PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync()`. They provide the following example code:

```
try
{
    var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

    // Handle the result of the FindAllPeersAsync call
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x8007048F)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Bluetooth is turned off");
    }
}
```

To detect device capabilities, look into the [PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.peerfinder.supporteddiscoverytypes) property.

Comment: But how to know if bluetooth doesn't exists.

Comment: See my edit for a `PeerFinder` property that should get you what you need.

Comment: I got 0x80342002 HResult exception... SurfaceRT only has Browse of `PeerFinder.SupportedDiscoveryTypes`. Desktop has none of it.

Comment: According to this MSDN [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx), that HResult means `The wireless LAN interface is shutting down and does not support the requested operation.`